# Use joined value in where clause

Tags: mysql, left-join

I want to use a where statement on a value from a joined table. Can't figure it out:

```
SELECT item.*, count(articles.authorid) AS articlecount 
FROM #_authors AS item 
LEFT JOIN #_articles AS articles ON (articles.authorid = item.id) 
WHERE item.published=1 
AND articlecount>3 
ORDER BY articlecount DESC
```

The orderby works fine, but when I add "AND articlecount>3" I get the error: "#1054 - Unknown column 'articlecount' in 'where clause'".

What is the best way to include the WHERE on articlecount? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For aggregate columns, you use `HAVING`, like this:

```
SELECT item.*, count(articles.authorid) AS articlecount 
FROM #_authors AS item 
LEFT JOIN #_articles AS articles ON (articles.authorid = item.id) 
WHERE item.published=1 
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 -- assuming there are 8 columns in item
HAVING count(articles.authorid) > 3 
ORDER BY 9 DESC -- assuming there are 8 columns in item
```

Comment: That worked. Adding "HAVING count(articles.authorid) > 3 " after the group by, did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT item.*, count(articles.authorid) AS articlecount 
    FROM #_authors AS item 
    LEFT JOIN #_articles AS articles ON (articles.authorid = item.id) 
    WHERE item.published=1 
    AND articlecount>3 
    ORDER BY articlecount DESC


articlecount refers to which table field?
if articlecount  is in #_author table then you have to write item.articlecount 

or articles.articlecount
```

Comment: articlecount isn't in a table, it is the resultvalue of the count on top of the statement. That count is on the articles table, but there is no database field named 'articlecount'. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try out using `HAVING` to filter by aggregated valeus:

```
WHERE item.published=1
HAVING count(articles.authorid) > 3
ORDER BY articlecount DESC
```